# Where should I place questions about freedesktop issues?

Tags: discussion

My [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124714/create-a-custom-xdg-dir-with-custom-icon) (about icons in a freedesktop compliant desktop), obvously, did not triggered anyone to answer. I suspect this is probably not the best place to ask those questions...
Is there a better place you know of? I once tryed to mail the freedesktop mailing list, but all I get are announces of server maintenance...

Comment: FDO mailing list seems like a good place to start - perhaps you didn't choose the right mailing list... Which one from http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo did you post your question to?

Comment: It was a long time ago, but I think it should have been the xdg one.

Comment: Actually, it was not: it was to the freedesktop one.
I'll try the xdg one. Seems more apropriate.

Comment: No comments so far...

Comment: Give it a couple of days - the xdg ml doesn't seem to be particularly high-volume one.

Comment: Still no comments...
Do you think it would be ok for me to repeat the same question in superuser or some place else, or would it be better to link to this question and ask them to come here to help me?

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you've asked in the right place. It may just be that no one knows how, or that it's not possible.

Comment: It could be... or maybe noone even noticed. It seems to be a really small-volume list.